# How to convert dict of different types into a pandas Series by doing sum on non scalar values?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am an absolute beginner in pandas, so the question below might not be very relevant. Nevertheless:

Given that I want to create a Series object with the following data:

```
from pandas import Series

data = {'c1' : 10, 'c2' : {'r1' : 1, 'r2' : 2}}
s = Series(data)
```

Is it possible to manipulate this Series in such a way that the result would be

```
print(s)
c1    10
c2     3
dtype: int64
```

Which is the result of summing up all entries in the inner dict (made by r1 and r2 keys)?

The alternative could be to explicitly handle the case outside the Series.

Comment: Will you always have at most two levels in your dictionary? Or could you end up with multiple nested levels?

Comment: @asongtoruin As of now, the data I am interested has only two levels. But I can see that changing in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dictionary only has one nested level and all values are numbers, you can flatten it as follows:

```
data = {k: sum(v.values()) if type(v) == dict else v for k, v in data.items()}
```

If you might have multiple levels, a short function can be used to sum the nested values:

```
import pandas as pd


def nested_itemsum(inp):
    total = 0
    if type(inp) == dict:
        total =  sum(nested_itemsum(v) for v in inp.values())
    else:
        total += inp
    return total

data = {'c1' : 10, 'c2' : {'r1' : 1, 'r2' : 2}}
data = {k: nested_itemsum(v) for k, v in data.items()}

s = pd.Series(data)

print(s)

data = {'c1' : 10, 'c2' : {'r1' : {'x1': 5, 'x2': 10}, 'r2' : 2}}
data = {k: nested_itemsum(v) for k, v in data.items()}

s = pd.Series(data)

print(s)
```

This prints:

```
c1    10
c2     3
dtype: int64
c1    10
c2    17
dtype: int64
```

As expected.

If you don't want to modify the input data, you can apply this to the series you create as follows:

```
data = {'c1' : 10, 'c2' : {'r1' : 1, 'r2' : 2}}

s = pd.Series(data)
s = s.apply(nested_itemsum)
```

and get the same result.

Comment: `data = {k: sum(v.values()) if type(v) == dict else v for k, v in data.items()}`

Comment: That is handling the data outside the Series object, which is what I already suggested in my question. I am interested in knowing whether there is something in the Series object that would allow me to do that without changing the input data.

Comment: @Vini you can do it either way round with the function - see the edit.